# Changing border colors of all tables in a document

Tags: tables, color

I have a document full of tables (think 8-10 tables) - already written. Some are tabulars, others are longtables. I do not want to substantially change the existing code.

What is the fastest way (in terms of markup) to convert the colors of border and frame lines from black to a specified color? I have xcolor loaded?

This is for a class file, and if a single redefinition of the internals of tabular or longtable could do it, that would be perfect.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tabular}{llll}\hline
Some & Thing & Here & Now \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{longtable}[l]{|p{2.5cm}|p{5.5cm}|p{6cm}} \hline
Word & Play & Table \\\hline
This & is & now \\\hline
That & was & then \\\hline
\end{longtable}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl} % <---
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{red} % <---

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tabular}{llll}\hline
Some & Thing & Here & Now \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{longtable}[l]{|p{2.5cm}|p{5.5cm}|p{6cm}} \hline
Word & Play & Table \\\hline
This & is & now \\\hline
That & was & then \\\hline
\end{longtable}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. Now, is there an easy way to do the same to any \rule{} lines in the document, and to all text (short of enclosing each block of text in \textcolor{color1}{})?

Comment: If you want to paint the town red try : `\color{red}`.

Comment: Well, not *that* red, but thanks!

Comment: Could you be more specific in your question on what you want to change. Maybe you can ask an new question with a minimal example saying this in red, this in blue ...

Comment: I just tried this. It gave me two error messages. (1) "!LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor." What does this mean and how might I fix it?  and (2) "Undefined color 'ProcessBlue'. See the xcolor package documentation..." This color worked fine right before...